# A theorem from Paul Erdős and De Brujin

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I recently tried to solve a problem as follow:

The sequence of real numbers $\{ a_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfies that $$a_{m+n} \leqslant a_m+a_n+f(m+n)$$ for all positive integers $m,n$, where the function $f$ is non-negative and increasing in the set $(0,+\infty)$. It is known that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ converges. Prove that the sequence $\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges or tends to $-\infty$.

It is noticed that this is a theorem from Paul Erdős and De Brujin, but there's no solution to such a theorem. I have trouble solving this. I tried to do it with the inspiration from a similar problem which is actually the case $f=0$ of the problem above, but failed. Looking for an answer, and it would be the best if you could provide some background information of this.

Comment: Here are similar questions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1784023p11769558, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1332920 (found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bm%2Bn%7D%20%5Cleqslant%20a_m%2Ba_n%2Bf(m%2Bn)%24)). The second has a link to https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A741&l=en which seems to contain the solution to your problem. Unfortunately, I do not speak Hungarian.

Comment: In fact, those two links are sources of my question. The problem in the link has the condition that $\sum \frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ diverges, instead of converges.

Comment: *“... those two links are sources of my question.”* – That would have been useful information in your question. But unless I am mistaken, the second part in https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A741&l=en is exactly your problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry that I forgot there's comment (second part) in this link. Thanks a lot.